# How can I use gpm from the console in the Ubuntu 20.04 installer?

Tags: command-line, system-installation, mouse, systemd, mouse-pointer

I am about to do a custom installation of Ubuntu Desktop which requires some command line work. To save myself time, I created a text file of the commands I wanted to use un hope of copy-pasting them between tmux panes. Unfortunately, I am having trouble getting GPM to work.

In order to be able to install GPM, I added the universe repository, but after doing so I was able to install it.

When I run `sudo systemctl enable gpm`, I get a message that gpm is `not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install`.
When I run `sudo systemctl start gpm`, the service fails to start. Running `journalctl -xe` revealed a likely sounding error: `cannot open/dev/mouse`.

[image]

As `/dev/mouse` did not exist, I tried making symbolic links to the likely looking things that do exist `/dev/input/mouse0` and `/dev/input/mice/`. I was then able to run `enable gpm` without error, but no cursor appeared. The pointer works fine in the GUI though.

A look at `systemctl status gpm` showed it still whining about /dev/mouse.

[image]

I have installed gpm in the Arch installer and it worked fine without any configuration. What do I have to do to configure the Ubuntu installer live usb to use gpm in the console?

Edit: Partial success!

If I run `gpm -m /dev/input/mice` or `gpm -m /dev/input/mouse0` gpm activates but does not work correctly. By that I mean that mouse input elicits a response, but not the right one.

Moving the mouse does a combination of scrolling, selecting, and copy-pasting while mouse clicks and the scroll wheel have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

OK I got it:

Start `gpm with` gpm -m /dev/psaux -t ps2`

For me that worked, so I added it to the config file

1. Create the file `/etc/gpm.conf`
2. Put in `gpm.conf` :

```
device=/dev/psaux
type=ps2
```

For other devices use `gpm -t help` to find a likely one. I have to admit it was not obvious to me that ps2 was the correct choice.